Iterate over a column like it's an array
Can I turn the columns into arrays and iterate over them to see if the date listed in the start_date column is between the start_date and end_date of all other rows?



pt_id
drug_name
start_date
end_date




12345
metoprolol
01/01/2020
03/01/2020


12345
lasix
02/01/2020
04/01/2020


12345
fentanyl
01/01/2020
03/01/2020


33333
metoprolol
03/02/2020
05/02/2020


33333
lasix
04/02/2020
06/02/2020



I need it to return which drugs a patient is taking at the same time. I thought if I could turn the columns into arrays, I could iterate over them and see if start_date of a row is between start_date and end_date of other rows, where the pt_id matches.
Is there a way to do this without having to read it into a data frame in Python?
I tried looking into stored procedures and T-SQL, where I found that a while loop exists, but I couldn't find where you can iterate over all the rows.

SQL is a set based language.  You don't loop through your records.

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. That way we can assist you.

While it's possible to use a CURSOR or a WHILE loop to iterate through a list of records, it's always better to find a set-based solution, as SQL uses a set-based engine.

This sounds like you need to do a self-join, not a loop. Something like:
SELECT
    M.t_id, M.drug_name, M.start_date, M.end_date,
    M2.drug_name AS other_drug_name,
    M2.start_date AS other_start_date,
    M2.end_date AS other_end_date
FROM Medications M
LEFT JOIN Medications M2
    ON M2.t_id = M.t_id
    AND M2.drug_name <> M.drug_name  -- Avoid join to same row
    AND M.start_date BETWEEN M2.start_date AND M2.end_date
ORDER BY M.t_id, M.start_date, M2.start_date




t_id
drug_name
start_date
end_date
otherdrug_name
otherstart_date
otherend_date




12345
metoprolol
2020-01-01
2020-01-03
fentanyl
2020-01-01
2020-01-03


12345
fentanyl
2020-01-01
2020-01-03
metoprolol
2020-01-01
2020-01-03


12345
lasix
2020-01-02
2020-01-04
metoprolol
2020-01-01
2020-01-03


12345
lasix
2020-01-02
2020-01-04
fentanyl
2020-01-01
2020-01-03


33333
metoprolol
2020-02-03
2020-02-05
null
null
null


33333
lasix
2020-02-04
2020-02-06
metoprolol
2020-02-03
2020-02-05



The above just checks the current row start_date against the start/end dates of other potentially active medications. To check for any overlap, you can change the condition to:
    AND M2.start_date <= M.end_date
    AND M.start_date <= M2.end_date

With now-symetrical results:



t_id
drug_name
start_date
end_date
otherdrug_name
otherstart_date
otherend_date




12345
fentanyl
2020-01-01
2020-01-03
metoprolol
2020-01-01
2020-01-03


12345
metoprolol
2020-01-01
2020-01-03
fentanyl
2020-01-01
2020-01-03


12345
metoprolol
2020-01-01
2020-01-03
lasix
2020-01-02
2020-01-04


12345
fentanyl
2020-01-01
2020-01-03
lasix
2020-01-02
2020-01-04


12345
lasix
2020-01-02
2020-01-04
metoprolol
2020-01-01
2020-01-03


12345
lasix
2020-01-02
2020-01-04
fentanyl
2020-01-01
2020-01-03


33333
metoprolol
2020-02-03
2020-02-05
lasix
2020-02-04
2020-02-06


33333
lasix
2020-02-04
2020-02-06
metoprolol
2020-02-03
2020-02-05



If you wish to combine the other drug names into a comma-separated list or similar, you can replace the join with a CROSS APPLY subquery and use the STRING_AGG() function to combine the other drug names into a single string.
SELECT
    M.t_id, M.drug_name, M.start_date, M.end_date,
    O.other_drug_names
FROM Medications M
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(M2.drug_name, ', ')
        WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY M2.drug_name)
        AS other_drug_names
    FROM Medications M2
    WHERE M2.t_id = M.t_id
    AND M2.drug_name <> M.drug_name  -- Avoid join to same row
    AND M2.start_date <= M.end_date  -- Check for any overlap (inclusive end dates)
    AND M.start_date <= M2.end_date
) O
ORDER BY M.t_id, M.start_date

Results:



t_id
drug_name
start_date
end_date
other_drug_names




12345
metoprolol
2020-01-01
2020-01-03
fentanyl, lasix


12345
fentanyl
2020-01-01
2020-01-03
lasix, metoprolol


12345
lasix
2020-01-02
2020-01-04
fentanyl, metoprolol


33333
metoprolol
2020-02-03
2020-02-05
lasix


33333
lasix
2020-02-04
2020-02-06
metoprolol



*I have assumed that your original posted dates were of the form dd/mm/yyyy and that the end-dates are inclusive. If your end-dates are exclusive, you would need to adjust the comparison operators.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

+1 for adding any overlap logic. Aside: It becomes a little more interesting if dosage is part of the table. A change in dosage would probably be worth including in the list, but that's just one of my gray cells twitching, not something mentioned by the OP.

If your source has a PK (say Id), you could change the M2.drug_name <> M.drug_name  to M2.Id <> M.Id to exclude same-row joins. This would then include overlapping orders for the same drug.  You can then add logic or filters to flag conflicting drug orders - multiple-same, multiple different doses, multiple in same family (including brand vs generic), or known drug interactions. But all that goes beyond the scope of this question. Hopefully this gives you something to build on.

You can also collect all date slices, join to the data from intersecting date intervals, collect the drugs by pt_it, start_date, end_date and eventually merge the intervals with same drugs for the patient:
with data(pt_id,drug_name, start_date, end_date) as (
    select 12345, 'metoprolol', {d'2020-01-01'}, {d'2020-01-03'} union all
    select 12345, 'lasix', {d'2020-01-02'}, {d'2020-01-04'} union all
    select 12345, 'fentanyl', {d'2020-01-01'}, {d'2020-01-03'} union all
    select 33333, 'metoprolol', {d'2020-02-03'}, {d'2020-02-05'} union all
    select 33333, 'lasix', {d'2020-02-04'}, {d'2020-02-06'} -- union all
)
, dateslices(rn, start_date, end_date) as (
    SELECT row_number() over(partition by pt_id order by start_date, end_date), start_date, end_date FROM (
        SELECT 
            pt_id, 
            dt as start_date,
            LEAD(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS end_date
        FROM data
        UNPIVOT (
            dt FOR type IN (
              start_date,
              end_date
            )
        ) t
    ) d
    where start_date <> end_date and end_date is not null
)
select pt_id, start_date, end_date, 
    string_agg(drug_name, ',') as drugs
from (
    select s.rn, 
        row_number() over(partition by d.pt_id order by s.start_date, s.end_date, d.drug_name) as name_rn,
        d.pt_id, s.start_date, s.end_date, d.drug_name
    from data d
    join dateslices s 
        on least(d.end_date, s.end_date) > greatest(d.start_date, s.start_date)
) d
group by rn, pt_id, start_date, end_date
order by pt_id, start_date
;

https://dbfiddle.uk/Moo9ATf7

To do as you're looking to do, this can all be done in a stored proc or SQL statement:

Create a temp table that will contain the rows you want to search through.
As needed, add indexes to columns on the temp table for better performance.
Insert the rows into the temp table
Open a cursor on the temp table and iterate through the rows as needed
CLOSE AND DEALLOCATE the cursor!  This is important for memory management.

If you can find any other way to get your expected result with just joins, then don't use cursors.

Whats the purpose of the temp table?

Replacing forward-only cursors with equivalent while loops where you pop each record off the top of a temp table is actually more performant. In this day and age, the use cases for cursors are really just limited to the special cases they can handle.
